# In “Member Berries”, is “member” just short for “remember”?

Tags: word-usage, shorthand, allusion

I enjoy watching *South Park* on current events. In its tense twentieth season, [*Member Berries*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_Berries) play a crucial role. While I’m afraid of not grasping the overarching concept entirely, I’d like this linguistic detail straightened out:

**Is *“’member”* a common shorthand for “*re*member”?** Is it in this particular instance?

If “member berries” were talking fruits that keep uttering nostalgic phrases, does “member” stand plainly for “*re*member”, or does it entail some broader indication? Does it simply drop a syllable colloquially, or is it part of some allusion?

Comment: *'Member* is indeed a contraction of *remember*. *Member Berries* may be a play on the word *remembrances*.

Comment: @Mick: So one may use it like *“’Member that time I…?”*? Is it nonstandard/slang?

Comment: To me it sounds like a small child's word.

Comment: I agree with @Colin. South Park is a scatological show about children and you should not try to use it to improve your English. It would be nice to know where the scriptwriters got *member berries* from. Most likely, it was one of their children.

Comment: I'm guessing that there were about five puns going on there.

Comment: @HotLicks Snerk! you said *member*...

Comment: @Mick I would say it's closer to *Memories*. Like a portmanteau: mem-ber-ries.

Comment: @Laurel You could well be right.

Comment: @Laurel - Members light the corners of my mind / Misty water-colored members / of the way we were

Answer (score 1):

I think it's clearly a contraction of *remember*. The berries constantly say things like "'member *this*?" and "I 'member *that*."

It's not a common contraction among people speaking proper English, but I believe it *is* a common mispronunciation among little children, for whom long words are harder to pronounce, and I believe this is what they're alluding to. They have high-pitched voices, which make them sound like little children. This contributes to the satire, because they're remembering things from years ago (like the original Star Wars trilogy), which little children wouldn't know about.